# Can I insert a random starting index in this Recursive DFS?

Tags: java, recursion, depth-first-search

This is a homework assignment but the question is not.  Among other things, I need to perform a DFS on a predetermined graph starting with the first element.  My `recursiveDFT` method does that.
I was just trying to figure out how to modify the algorithm to start with the last index, or a middle one.  It's eluding me.

```
public void recursiveDFT() {
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfVertices; i++) {
        if (!vertex[i].getColor().equals("white"))
            vertex[i].setColor("white");
        if (pi[i] != null)
            pi[i] = null;
    }
    time = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfVertices; i++) {
        if (vertex[i].getColor().equals("white"))
            recursiveDFTVisit(i);
    }
}//recursiveDFT

public void recursiveDFTVisit(int u) {
    vertex[u].setColor("gray");
    time++;
    d[u] = time;
    vertex[u].visit();
    for (int column = 0; column < numberOfVertices; column++) {
        if(edge[u][column] == 1 && vertex[column].getColor().equals("white")) {
            pi[column] = vertex[u];
            recursiveDFTVisit(column);
        }
    }
    vertex[u].setColor("black");
    f[u] = ++time;
}
```

Comment: Are your graphs directed? If they are, you may not find the entire tree if you want to start at the other end.

Comment: If it's directed, there is a possibility that you can't traverse the whole tree if you don't start at the root… So what is it you are trying to do, exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to start from a different point but still check the whole tree the best way would probably be to reorder your vertex array. To start at a different part of vertex[] you'd simply change the starting value of i in your first for loop. As mentioned though, this might prevent you from walking the whole tree unless you redesign your for loop to ensure it still hits every node. You could for instance, start at length-1 and then decrement i until it goes below zero. That works fine if you just want to start at the end and go in reverse, but if you want to get any more complex ordering you're better off just reordering your vertexes.